# Fullscreen mode in chrome flicker the screen with Gnome Wayland

Tags: google-chrome, wayland

When I put chrome in full screen the screen is flashing.

In other browsers and Xorg it works normally.

[Chrome Flicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgAJl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: [Screen flickers on fullscreen in chrome and gnome-mpv](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/bzza8k/screen_flickers_on_fullscreen_in_chrome_and/). Basically it is to disable chrome hardware acceleration. How to disable is shown here: [How To Disable Hardware Acceleration](https://ccm.net/faq/35743-google-chrome-how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration)